# how to carry out pre-processing of satellite images in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have satellite images that i need to carry out atmospheric correction in matlab. how do i write the code in matlab for atmospheric correction. I have tried imadjust, histeq, and adapthisteq and there is also histogram equalization. i get an output when i run the code. Am just not sure that the code actually does the atmospheric correction. here is the code

```
image1 = imread('200904010000-msg-ch05-k.pgm');
image2 = imread('200904010000-msg-ch08-k.pgm');
[image3] = imread('200904010000-msg-ch11-k.pgm');
images = {image1, image2, image3};
image1 = images{1};
image2 = images{2};
image3 = images{3};
image1_imadjust = imadjust(image1);
image1_histeq = histeq(image1);
image1_adapthisteq = adapthisteq(image1);
imshow(image1);
title('Original');
figure, imshow(image1_imadjust);
title('Imadjust');
figure, imshow(image1_histeq);
title('Histeq');
figure, imshow(image1_adapthisteq);
title('Adapthisteq');image2_imadjust = imadjust(image2);
image2_histeq = histeq(image2);
image2_adapthisteq = adapthisteq(image2);
figure, imshow(image2);
title('Original');
figure, imshow(image2_imadjust);
title('Imadjust');
```

Comment: What is the atomspheric correction algorithm you are trying to implement?  Where does it come from and what does it do?

Comment: Please explain in detail what you want to achieve. Imagine that your audience will know lots about MATLAB and programming, but not much about the field that you work in.

Comment: Atmospheric corrections are to remove atmospheric effects. Atmospheric correction improves the accuracy of image. The values that are recorded at any pixel location do not reflect the true reflectance that is leaving the ground. The things to be removed are the brightness due to reflectance of the target that is of interest and brightness of the atmosphere itself.

Comment: I have an a satellite image acquired from SEVIRI sensor onboard Meteosat Second Generation 2.The purpose of atmospheric correction is to retrieve the surface reflectance that has the characteristics of the surface properties from remotely sensed imagery by removing the atmospheric effects. The things to be removed are the brightness due to reflectance of the target that is of interest and brightness of the atmosphere itself

Comment: @Mariam: Let me put it like this: what you're essentially trying to do is image processing; however, the term 'atmospheric correction' does not represent any standard algorithm for the above said. As such, please explain clearly, the image-processing algorithm you are trying to implement. It would help if you were to provide a sample input and output.

Comment: @RoneyMichael, its not image processing. it is pre-processing to remove excess brightness

Comment: Define "excess" brightness, as well as how you would tell if you were genuinely improving image accuracy or not.  If you don't know how, talk to your boss/supervisor. Incidentally, what is the difference between the three images in the sample code? Are you sure you're not supposed to be doing some sort of comparison between images taken at different frequencies?